# WinForms how to show specific panel from FlowDirectionPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation, panel

i have the following `FlowDirectionPanel` http://prntscr.com/aao6lt as you can see those are achievements for a poker game.When you get a new achievement a yes/no messageBox pops up and it ask's you if you want to go and check out your new acquirement if you press yes I want to be able to automatically navigate to the newly unlocked achievement which are contained in the FlowDirectionPanel which looks like in the image above. Also each achievement is contained in another panel which is children of the flowPanel if you look closer you can see that they have some outline border. I create and add the panels dynamically but they do have names which can help me to navigate to the desired panel. This is how i create them:

```
        public void PanelForAchievements(Form currentForm, FlowLayoutPanel flp, AchivementRequirements achivement)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel retFlp = flp;
        string pGetAchivementName = @"pGet" + achivement.Name;
        string lbAchivementName = @"lb" + achivement.Name;
        string lbAchivementRewardName = @"lb" + achivement.Name + @"Reward";
        string cbGetAchivementName = @"cbGet" + achivement.Name;
        string pbAchivementName = @"pb" + achivement.Name;
        var pGetAchivement = new Panel
        {
            Name = pGetAchivementName,
            Size = new Size(retFlp.Width, 100),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        };
        currentForm.Controls.Add(pGetAchivement);

        var lbAchivement = new Label
        {
            Name = lbAchivementName,
            Location = new Point(pGetAchivement.Location.X, pGetAchivement.Location.Y),
            Size = new Size(135, 30),
            AutoSize = false,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)0),
            Text = achivement.TitleText,
        };

        var lbAchivementReward = new Label
        {
            Name = lbAchivementRewardName,
            AutoSize = true,
            Top = (pGetAchivement.Height - pGetAchivement.Height) / 2,
            Text = achivement.RewardLabelText,
            TabIndex = 2,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Location = new Point(lbAchivement.Location.X, lbAchivement.Location.Y + lbAchivement.Height + 5)
        };

        var cbGetAchivement = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = cbGetAchivementName,
            AutoCheck = false,
            AutoSize = true,
            Location = new Point(lbAchivement.Location.X + lbAchivement.Width + 10, lbAchivement.Location.Y),
            TabIndex = 1,
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        };
        achivement.IsUnlocked(MainPoker.AllAchievements[achivement.EnumCasted], achivement.Requirement,cbGetAchivement);

        var pbAchivement = new PictureBox
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
            Name = pbAchivementName,
            Dock = DockStyle.Right,
            BackgroundImageLayout = achivement.PictureBoxImageLayout,
            //Location = new Point(pGetAchivement.Right, pGetAchivement.Location.Y),
            Size = new Size(145, 90),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            TabIndex = 9,
            TabStop = false,
            Image = achivement.PackPreview,
        };

        pGetAchivement.Controls.Add(lbAchivement);
        pGetAchivement.Controls.Add(lbAchivementReward);
        pGetAchivement.Controls.Add(cbGetAchivement);
        pGetAchivement.Controls.Add(pbAchivement);

        retFlp.Controls.Add(pGetAchivement);

        achivement.Title = lbAchivement;
        achivement.RewardLabel = lbAchivementReward;
        achivement.Unlocked = cbGetAchivement;
        achivement.Preview = pbAchivement;
    }
```

It's just simple code and this is how i initialize them :

```
    public static RoyalFlush RoyalFlush = new RoyalFlush(1, new Tuple<string, int?>("Royal Card Pack", 100000));
    private readonly CreatePanels _createAchivementPanels = new CreatePanels();
    foreach (var achi in AchivementRequirements.AchivementList)
    {
                    _createAchivementPanels.PanelForAchievements(this, pAchievementsCards, achi);
//im also doing other stuff here..
//pAchivementsCards is the name of the FlowDirectionPanel
    }
```

Now by the time the yes/no messageBox is shown i already know which achievement is unlocked and also my achievements have classes as seen above `public static RoyalFlush RoyalFlush` and those classes have property - `Name` which obviously contains the name of the achievement im using this name to create respective names for each control i create from `public static RoyalFlush RoyalFlush`for example :

```
string pGetAchivementName = @"pGet" + achivement.Name;
```

p stands for `panel` and i simply just get the current achievement name using the property `achivement.Name` and we end up with something like this : pRoyalFlush as a name for our panel. Now that i know the name of the panel and which achievement is being unlocked i need to navigate through my `FlowDirectionPanel` and find the specific panel and leave the focus there. I have no idea how to do that i will show an example with pictures of what i want if it's not clear by now :

- First we unlock new achievement and we get the yes/no mbox : http://prnt.sc/aaodyr
- Now we press the Yes button which will redirect us to my new form and show us the achievement `FlowDirectionPanel` : h.t.t.p.:/./.prntscr.com/aaofft here the program see's that the achievement for Full House is completed and it should show it in the middle of the screen with a nice border just like so : h.t.t.p.:././.prntscr.com/aaoh40

I dont have reputation to post more than 2 links so i had to put some dots in them ..
It's my first question and my native language is not English so excuse me for any mistakes I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may make some foreahc loop, where you compare names, and then, when you find the control you need, scroll your flowlayoutpanel to it. For example, my flowlayoutpanel has 4 buttons, and only 2 of them are visible, and I want to scroll to button4:

```
        foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            if ((c as Button).Name == "button4")
            {
                (c as Button).Focus();
                flowLayoutPanel1.ScrollControlIntoView(c);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Hope I andrestand your question correctly.

Comment: any idea how to add a border around the panel ? Do i need to add additional control to make it work or the panels have such property ?

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852829/i-want-to-make-a-panel-have-a-thick-border-can-i-set-this-somehow)

Comment: Also is there any reason why you are safe-casting instead of specifying the control instead ?

Comment: @KOPEUE, actually no, there is no reason :). You could just use `c.Name == "..."` and `c.Focus()`. My mistake :)